# Difference between PSCP and Copy-Item in for remote copy with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 windows-servers. I need to run a PowerShell script on server A which will transfer a file (on server A) to server B.
What is the best (most secure) way to do this? I found out 2 solutions on the internet and it's not very clear for me what's the difference between them.

Option 1: `Copy-Item`

```
Copy-Item -Path \\serverb\c$\programs\temp\test.txt -Destination \\servera\c$\programs\temp\test.txt;
```

Option 2: `PSCP` (.exe)

```
if(!$pass)    {$pass = Read-Host 'Enter Password'}
$pscp         = "`'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe`'"

"cmd /c ${pscp} -r -pw ${pass} ...
```

Option 3: Another (better) option..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is to create a share specifically for exchange between your two servers and by the way, you will can managing authorization on share.

Your second option is fine if your remote host has a SSH server because SCP protocol uses SSH for data transfer.